# (flutter) how do I make the container resize symmetrically

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, scale

I have some containers located on the screen with the Positioned widget.
They scale according to the text inside them.

Right now, they scale to the right:

```
---[---]--- -> ---[-----]- (I have added two -- to the line)
```

I want them to to this.

```
---[---]--- -> --[-----]--
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *PositionedWidget* enclose Rows, Columns in a container and play with their *Size* and *Alignment* parameter e.g.

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to container to be in a very specific an non-symmetric locations on the screen. I tried to do it with empty sized boxes, but once the container scales everything breaks down.